# When creating dynamic textboxes a space allocates always when creating the next set of dynamic text box set

Tags: html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function AddingTextBoxes() {
                var NumOfText=$("#NumOfTextBoxes").val();
                $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').find('input').remove();
                for (i = 0; i < NumOfText; i++) {
                    var txtBox = "<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/><br>"
                    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBox);
                }
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="PHPForms">
                <!--Designing PHP forms dynamically-->
                <label>Form Heading</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Number of text boxes would needed</label>
                <input id="NumOfTextBoxes" type="text" />
                <button onclick=" return AddingTextBoxes()">Click</button>
                <div id="NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes" name="Texty"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code though Im able to create dynamic text boxes when Im entering a value again the next set of text boxes create after having a spaces. How can I avoid that? It is a code which is a combination of HTML, JQuery, JavaScript.

Comment: what you want to do is remove the space between the text boxes is it?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. What whitespace is where? Can you show us screenshots, or link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Im really sorry. The earlier code I had posted should be corrected. I edited it back... Will u now be able to catch what I said? Im entering a value to the text box and it perfectly creates the num of text boxes what need. Bt when I enter another value and click the button again it allocates a space where the earlier text boxes were and newly created text boxes create below that space. So I need to remove that space and create text boxes always right below the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the white space is because of this line in your function:

```
$('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').find('input').remove();
```

The above line only removes the `input` elements from the DIV `NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes` and leaves the `<br>` tags which cause the whitespace.

You can simply use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to *remove all child nodes* from a selected element.

What you have to do is replace the above line with

```
$('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').empty();
```

[Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jVgL7/)